# application.properties file cannot be open in Spring tool suite after import the project from an another computer

Tags: spring-boot

İ am new to spring boot. I have developed a rest api project on my laptop. It works properly. After that, I had to move this project to my desktop computer.  Both environments are same. After importing  (to STS- sprinh tool suite 4)the project to the desktop computer, i am unable to open application.properties file through the STS. I am thankful if anyone help me to  fix this.

Comment: Are you able to see the `application.properties` on folder `src/main/resources/` on Windows Os? if you are, then you would need to set by default as `resources` that folder.

Comment: what message do u get when you double click on file

Comment: @chameeraMPerera show us the error message or whatever it is displayed.